# how to let javscript to change the element of the html which is in outside of folder

Tags: javascript

My project includes files and folders, like:

```
--My Project
  |--index.htm
  |--index.js
  |--auth-system(folder)
      |--signin.html
      |--signup.html
      |--signout.html
      |--auth.js
```

I want to change some element values of index.htm using auth.js. My code in auth.js is like:

```
document.getElementById('userName').value = "ok"
```

where userName is the id name of a list element in index.htm

```
<li class="nav-item active">
<a id="userName" class="nav-link" href="#" target="myFrame">User</a>
</li>
```

I included auth.js in the index.htm by adding

```
<!-- Authentication js -->
<script type ="text/javascript" src="auth-system/auth.js"></script>
```

but it doesn't work...

Can you help me? thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can external JavaScript access DOM elements from a different file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548969/can-external-javascript-access-dom-elements-from-a-different-file)

Comment: Use `.text = "ok"` instead of `.value = "ok"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the script tag after the element you want to modify (or before the closing `body` tag) and use `document.getElementById('userName').text = "ok"` instead of `document.getElementById('userName').value = "ok"`.

**./index.htm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<li class="nav-item active">
<a id="userName" class="nav-link" href="#" target="myFrame">User</a>
</li>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./auth-system/auth.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**./auth-system/auth.js**

```
document.getElementById('userName').text = "ok";
```

Comment: Later you can encapsulate the required statements under a function and call it on load

`<body onload="myfunc()">` where `myfunc()` executes the required statements inside it.

Comment: thank. Is it possible call javascript in auth.js to update the element in index.html. I want to do in this way.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Try putting the `<script>` tag at the end of the body and also attach the contents of both the files.

Comment: thanks. How to do for attaching the contents of both the files? I don't understand...

Comment: @affeto Edit your question and post your `html` and `js` file there.

Comment: Use `.text = "ok"` instead of `.value = "ok"`. [edited]

Comment: Edit your `html` code and put the whole `html` file there.

Comment: I have tried this on my own local system and this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `<a>` tag and some `<li>` tags. None of 'em gets a *value* attribute as per valid HTML is concerned. The *value* attributes are only available to form elements like `<input>`, `<option>` or the likes. I'm assuming you want to change the text from *User* to *ok*. In that case, just change the line in your auth.js to:

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = "ok";
};
```

Comment: Thanks! the compiling error disappears, however value doesn't change from User to ok

Comment: the signin.html, signout.html and signup.html are displayed in a frame inside of index.htm. auth.js is used to work with sign**.html, but I also want it affect some element in index.htm.